# Find all possible digits such that $\overline{ab}\mid\overline{a0b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

My question is : how to find all possibilities for the $\overline{ab}\mid\overline{a0b}$ if we rewrite as $$10a+b\mid100a+b$$ it can easy to show for $b=0$ it is has solution like $$10\mid100\\20\mid200\\...$$ and for $$a=4,b=5 \to 45\mid405$$ but I am for stuck to solve it for more possible numbers. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it as$$100a+b = (10a+b)k \\
10(10-k)a = (k - 1)b$$

Now we only need to see $5$ (quite) easy cases:

---

Since $a > 0$:

- $a=1 $: $$10(10-k) = (k-1)b \implies b = \cfrac{10(10-k)}{k-1}$$
  Since $b<10$, we must have $$\frac{10-k}{k-1}<1 \implies 5 < k \le 10$$
  Checking for these cases, we get $k = 6,7,10$

---

- $a=2 $: $$10(10-k)2 = (k-1)b \implies b = \cfrac{ 10\cdot2(10-k)}{k-1}$$
  Since $b<10$, we must have $$\frac{10-k}{k-1}<\frac 12 \implies 7 < k \le 10$$
  Checking for $k=8, 9$, we do not get an integer result. $k=10$ is valid.

---

- $a=3 $: $$10(10-k)3 = (k-1)b \implies b = \cfrac{ 10\cdot3(10-k)}{k-1}$$
  Since $b<10$, we must have $$\frac{10-k}{k-1}<\frac 13 \implies 8 < k \le 10$$
  Checking for $k=9$, we do not get an integer result. $k=10$ is valid.

---

- $a=4:$ $$10(10-k)3 = (k-1)b \implies b = \cfrac{ 10\cdot4(10-k)}{k-1}$$
  Since $b<10$, we must have $$\frac{10-k}{k-1}<\frac 14 \implies 8 < k \le 10$$
  Checking for $k=9, 10$, we see these are valid $k$.

---

- For $a\ge 5$, it is impossible to get $b<10$ by the same argument.

---

So, now you have all the cases done.